# How to check if quaternion is rotated past defined degrees from level

Tags: 3d, quaternions, euler-angles

I have a quaternion, q, and I need to determine if it is rotated beyond a certain number of degrees past level in both the X/Y axes. Any easy shortcut would obviously be to convert the quat to x/y/z Euler angles and then compare x/x values to the angle limits, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution should be to find exact angle between your quaternion and `Identity` one.

I don't know which `Quaternion` implementation do you use, many of them have some helper methods to compute such things. If your implementation doesn't support this you can look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167828) answer for help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "swing twist decomposition", it split rotation with two component

Decompose the rotation on to 2 parts.
   1. Twist - rotation around the "direction" vector
   2. Swing - rotation around axis that is perpendicular to "direction" vector
   The rotation can be composed back by 
   rotation = swing * twist

[Component of a quaternion rotation around an axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684269/component-of-a-quaternion-rotation-around-an-axis)
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/for/decomposition/