# How to subtract component of quaternion along a given axis?

Tags: vector, rotation, quaternions

For example, to subtract out the component of a vector a along unit vector b, you just take the dot product of a and b and multiply by the vector b.  Then you just subtract a•b*b from a to take out the component of the vector along b.

How do you do this for a rotation?
Rotations can be represented by euler angles, rotation matrices, or quaternions.  The quaternion is a certain rotation about an euler axis, but how do you subtract out the component of the rotation about a given axis?

Comment: Look at my answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684269/component-of-a-quaternion-rotation-around-an-axis/22401169#22401169

This function split rotation into two components , parallel to passed axis and perpendicalar to passed axis. This look exactly what you want.

Comment: I believe I saw your post before.  However, it only finds the component of rotation along a certain direction, but does not instruct how to subtract such a thing from a quaternion.

Comment: It finds two quaternions one is " component of rotation along a certain direction"  and second is "substraction" of this component from original rotation

Comment: q.x = x * sin(theta / 2)
q.y = y * sin(theta / 2)
q.z = z * sin(theta / 2)
q.w = cos(theta / 2)
Is your solution assuming that is how quaternions are represented?  Because if you simply project onto x, y, and z without anything else and then just add q.w onto the end of the twist or swing or whichever it was, I feel like it doesn't likely represent what I am trying to do here?

Comment: You decide represent or not, anyway i don't know other similar decomposition. 

Try to verify using geometric meaning. It exactly does Swing Twist decomposition