# How to nullify rotation on an arbitrary axis in a quaternion?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, quaternions

I am attempting to disallow rotations around the y axis as is implemented in the 360 video here: at https://www.omnivirt.com/ on a mobile device. If you look on your mobile device and tilt the phone left and right only manipulating the y value as seen in here (rotating like the hands of a clock):

[image]

there are no rotations over that axis. However in my implementation I am taking that gamma value and using it for a rotation around the y axis.  I believe I need to disallow rotation around the y axis but still use gamma in calculations  for other rotations in order to achieve a similar effect. I have the logic here for creating the device quaternion:

```
//Degrees to Radians conversion
    var degtorad = Math.PI / 180;
    var z = this.alpha * degtorad / 2;
    var x = this.beta * degtorad / 2;
    var y = this.gamma * degtorad / 2;

    var cX = Math.cos(x);
    var cY = Math.cos(y);
    var cZ = Math.cos(z);
    var sX = Math.sin(x);
    var sY = Math.sin(y);
    var sZ = Math.sin(z);

    // ZXY quaternion construction.
    var w = cX * cY * cZ - sX * sY * sZ;
    var x = sX * cY * cZ - cX * sY * sZ;
    var y = cX * sY * cZ + sX * cY * sZ;
    var z = cX * cY * sZ + sX * sY * cZ;

    var deviceQuaternion = quat.fromValues(x, y, z, w);
```

On this page ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345145/nullify-zero-out-cancel-rotation-in-an-arbitrary-axis-in-a-quaternion ) I’ve found mathematical solutions but am not sure how to implement them.

I am looking for a way to modify my javascript code to achieve this effect.  Thank you!

Comment: not an answer to your question but you might find a solution [here](https://github.com/dorukeker/gyronorm.js)

Comment: Hope this can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684269/component-of-a-quaternion-rotation-around-an-axis/22401169#22401169